# Is it possible to do routing scope inheritance in CakePHP3?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm doing a big refactoring and i want to add some scope inside my app but i'm stuck on this problem:

I have a main scope "/api" and i want to have a sub-scope inside named "/user", is it possible in CakePHP3 ?

Here is my code:

```
Router::scope('/api', function ($routes) {
    //USERS
    Router::scope('/user', ['controller' => 'Users'], function ($routes) {
        $routes->connect('/saveUser', ['action' => 'save']);
        $routes->connect('/editUser/:id', ['action' => 'edit'])
            ->setPass(['id'])
            ->setPatterns(['id' => '\d+']);
        $routes->connect('/deleteUser/:id', ['action' => 'delete'])
            ->setPass(['id'])
            ->setPatterns(['id' => '\d+']);
        $routes->connect('/deleteUser/:id/deleteImage', ['action' => 'deleteImage'])
            ->setPass(['id'])
            ->setPatterns(['id' => '\d+']);
    });
});
```

The error page say "Missing Method in ApiController, The action users is not defined in ApiController" but i'm calling UsersController.

Thanks for help

[SOLVED]

```
Router::scope('/api', function ($routes) {
    //USERS
    $routes->scope('/user', ['controller' => 'Users'], function ($innerRoutes) {
        $innerRoutes->connect('/saveUser', ['action' => 'save']);
        $innerRoutes->connect('/editUser/:id', ['action' => 'edit'])
            ->setPass(['id'])
            ->setPatterns(['id' => '\d+']);
        $innerRoutes->connect('/deleteUser/:id', ['action' => 'delete'])
            ->setPass(['id'])
            ->setPatterns(['id' => '\d+']);
        $innerRoutes->connect('/deleteUser/:id/deleteImage', ['action' => 'deleteImage'])
            ->setPass(['id'])
            ->setPatterns(['id' => '\d+']);
    });
});
```

Comment: Please post your answer as an answer and not as part of your question. you can read more about how to answer your own questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)